# How to make a Google Maps URL to get both marker and terrain?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, markers, basemap, url

In the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started examples

- We can have a marker,
  https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518%2C-122.3316393
- Or we can choose a basemap, e.g., terrain,
  https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&center=-33.712206%2C150.311941&zoom=12&basemap=terrain

But how can we have both a marker and terrain? I can't hack together a URL that will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the offical api.
This is not really documented by google maps, so it could change from time to time:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/47.5951518,-122.3316393/@47.5951518,-122.3316393,10z/data=!5m1!1e4

Scheme:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/{lat},{lng}/@{lat},{lng},{zoom}z/data={style}
```

Style:

- Terrain: `/data=!5m1!1e4`
- Earth: `/data=!3m1!1e3`

Zoom:

```
1-19z
```

This works in the desktop version / browser. Not in a mobile app.

Comment: OK! I'll take your warnings seriously, and not get burnt.